# How do I generate Creative Commons license information?

Tags: packages, licensing

I need to include some licensing information on the back cover of a free CC-licensed book. Instead of frankly mentioning the license ("This work is licensed under CC-by-nc-sa, Google knows more"), I'd like to have complete information about the rights it gives, i.e. comparable to what the license description says on their [site](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-nc-sa/2.5/), both images and text. I imagined the following to be in the code for that:

```
\usepackage{creativecommons}
...
\license[2.5]{by-nc-sa}
...
% images only
\shortlicense[3.0]{by-nc-sa}
```

Does anyone know of a package that makes such licensing notices easier?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

For typesetting the Creative Commons licence logos you could use the [`cclicenses`](http://ctan.org/pkg/cclicenses) package.

Comment: I wonder how I missed that one... :-/ Thanks for the hint, too bad it's a bit outdated...

Comment: Most of the icons by this package look good enough, with the exception of the \ccnc (non-commercial) icon.  Apparently that thing is rendered by putting a rotated backslash over an encircled '$'.  When using only the default Computer Modern font however, that backslash is too short to cover the entire circle.

Comment: @Giel @rassie the ccicons package looks a lot better than these icons do. See my answer.

Answer (score 51):

The [`ccicons`](https://ctan.org/pkg/ccicons) package contains much prettier icons than those provided by [`cclicenses`](https://ctan.org/pkg/cclicenses).

I don't think there is a package that  defines macros for inserting CC license text into TeX documents, but it would be easy enough to make one.

See also [this post](http://creativecommons.org/weblog/entry/4270) on the creative commons website.

Comment: Just curious (and lazy): are these as good as grabbing the PDF from the creative commons website, as suggested by Lennart?

Comment: They look pretty darn close to the real deal. I expect they are just the SVGs turned into a font...

Answer (score 35):

I wrote a package for this :) See also [Creative Commons Licence on SX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/226788/32320).

The package is called [doclicense](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/doclicense). Check out the following mini example:

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[
    type={CC},
    modifier={by-nc-sa},
    version={3.0},
]{doclicense}
\begin{document}
\doclicenseThis
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately this mini example does not compile under MiKTeX 2.9 on windows7 64bits (doclicense packaged 2015-08-04). It complains that doclicense.sty is not found. Also the miktex automatic detection of missing packages fails to notice this package is not installed. I installed it from the Miktex package manager, but nothing changes.

Comment: @SiliconValley: There was a problem with this package in TeX Live/MacTeX but it [should be fixed now](https://github.com/ypid/latex-packages/issues/1). Please open an issue if not.

Comment: @ypid I'm making a print-only document and don't need the hyperlinking, and I don't see an easy way to remove it. How can I do that?

Comment: @Azor-Ahai I have never tried that and I don’t really think that it makes sense to support this. The hyperrefs will not be visible when printing. If you really want to do it you can easily achieve this by redefining the \href macro (in a way that it just expands to the link text). You could also pdf-print the document (using CUPS for example) which will also remove the hyperlinks.

Comment: Would it possible for the command `doclicense` to respect the twocolumn option of a document ?

Comment: @jowe_19 You are right, there was a bug with documents in twocolumn. Refer to: https://github.com/ypid/latex-packages/issues/50 Note: Please report issues in the bug tracker, not here.

Answer (score 8):

Personally I thought that looked pretty bad. I solved it by downloading the relevant button from http://creativecommons.org/about/downloads as svg, converting it to pdf with Inkscape and including it as an image.

I did have to rename it, it seems that the two dots in the file name, by-nc-sa.eu.pdf confuses something, so you get an error, but by renaming it to by-nc-sa.pdf it worked fine.

Importing the eps file also worked, except that I got cutmarks around the button!