# Inserting a Creative Commons Licence into a LaTeX document

Tags: packages, copyright, licensing

I'd like to insert a CC license on a manuscript (a book or report). I've seen the page for downloading the [CC icons](http://creativecommons.org/about/downloads/), and also some questions asked in the forum [CC logo](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/20308/creative-commons-logo) and [Generate CC information](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1725/how-do-i-generate-creative-commons-license-information).

However, I do not get how to create the actual thing!

**Q:** Can you please provide an example of a license info page (*MWE*)? That would be really helpful!

Comment: As an additional point to this: in addition to adding the license in a human-readable way, you probably want to include it in a machine-readable way as well. The standard for this is XMP. There is a LaTeX package called "xmpincl" for the purpose: https://blogs.igalia.com/juanjo/2006/06/07/embedding-license-info-inside-a-pdf-with-latex/ https://creativecommons.org/2004/06/22/xmpembeddingforpdflatex/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Based on the answer by @raniere-silva, and information on the [Creative Commons page](http://creativecommons.org/), I manage to put the information in a way I liked.

I went to the CC page and download the logo (in svn), based in the kind of license I choose. Using `InkScape` I transformed into pdf.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[framemethod=tikz]{mdframed}

\definecolor{cccolor}{rgb}{.67,.7,.67}

\begin{document}

\begin{mdframed}[outerlinecolor=black,outerlinewidth=2pt,linecolor=cccolor,middlelinewidth=3pt,roundcorner=10pt]
  This work is licensed under a Creative Commons Attribution-ShareAlike 3.0 Unported License.
  \begin{center}
    \includegraphics[scale=2]{by-nc-sa.pdf}
  \end{center}
\end{mdframed}

\end{document}
```

The final result was

[image: Logo of the Creative Commons licesnse]

Answer (score 37):

I wrote a package for this as I used something similar as [Raniere Silva](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/22451/raniere-silva) and I wanted it a bit more clean :)

The package is called [doclicense](https://github.com/ypid/latex-packages/tree/master/doclicense). Check out the following mini example:

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[
    type={CC},
    modifier={by-nc-sa},
    version={3.0},
]{doclicense}
\begin{document}
\doclicenseThis
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You forgot the `[hidelinks]` option to `hyperref` ;-)

Comment: @kap This depends on your preference. A few reasons for not using `hidelinks` for this MWE here: This example is not about hyperref. Default options are supposed to be sane. And last but not least, it it actually useful to see here in the screenshot what text is actually a hyperlink.

Comment: How would I scale the whole `\doclicenseThis` down, so it is going to be smaller?

Comment: @nath https://github.com/ypid/latex-packages/issues/30 might help which was recently released. Otherwise, feel free to open an issue at https://github.com/ypid/latex-packages/issues with more input about your use case.

Comment: One nice thing about this package is that it also includes the license as metadata (XMP) :)

Answer (score 12):

There is a package that do it for you (the documentation is only available in portuguese at the moment): https://gitorious.org/mundo-livre/creative-commons-licenses-for-latex.

For my documents I use the code below in the cover.

```
 \begin{tabular}{|p{.9\textwidth}|}
 \hline
 This work is licensed under a Creative Commons Attribution-ShareAlike 3.0 Unported License.
 \begin{center}
 \includegraphics[scale=1]{cc-by-sa.png}
 \end{center}\\
 \hline
 \end{tabular}
```

Comment: I would always go for a vector graphic format for example PDF (or SVG). \includegraphics can handle PDFs as well as PNGs ;)

Answer (score 12):

The `ccicons` LaTeX package provides a set of icons to represent the Creative Commons licenses. There are macros for each icon, as well as shortcuts that allow you to simply drop a specific set of license icons for a license type (e.g., `\ccbyncsa` will add the CC logo, the attribution icon, the noncommercial (in US dollars) icon, and the share-and-share alike icon)).

Icons are a PostScript Type 1 font, so they scale cleanly.

https://www.ctan.org/pkg/ccicons?lang=en

Comment: Could you explain a bit more about what the package provides?

Comment: @muarithmia: For instance, you can use `\ccbysa` to output icon showing cc by sa. Very simple usage. If you go want to have the "original" figures, go for the [doclicense](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/doclicense) package.

Comment: Fontawesome and fontawesome5 will get you some of these icons, too.

Answer (score 6):

The Creative Commons icons are also included in the [Font Awesome font](https://fontawesome.com/icons?d=gallery&q=creative%20commons), which is available in LaTeX via the [`fontawesome5` package](https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/fontawesome5):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontawesome5}

\begin{document}
    This answer is under the CC-BY-SA 4.0 International license \faCreativeCommons\ \faCreativeCommonsBy\ \faCreativeCommonsSa
\end{document}
```

[image: example_output]

Answer (score 2):

I started using the brilliant https://www.ctan.org/pkg/doclicense package for this. For an article prepared with the amsart class, I wanted the license notice to appear as a footnote. Using `\thanks` with `\doclicenseThis` did not work so well, so I ended up using the following:

```
\maketitle
\insert\footins{% taken from amsart.cls
  \normalfont\footnotesize
  \interlinepenalty\interfootnotelinepenalty
  \splittopskip\footnotesep \splitmaxdepth \dp\strutbox
  \floatingpenalty10000 \hsize\columnwidth
  This is a post-print (accepted manuscript) version of
  this paper, which has been published in ... and is 
  available from \url{...}.
  \doclicenseThis\par}
```