# how to write make rectangle box and write in it

Tags: tables, framed

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\begin{document}
\title{GROUP THEORY}\bfseries
\maketitle
\section{ALGEBRIC SYSTEM :}
NOTE: The algebraic system define over operator $\star$ , which is \emph{closed} and \emph{associative} is called SEMIGROUP.
\end{document}
```

I want to write my last sentence in rectangular box so that i can highlight it.

Comment: Is `\fbox{}` what you want?

Comment: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/38354/make-an-example-and-shaded-box-like-in-the-book/38369#38369

Answer (score 9):

One option is to use the `tcolorbox` package. There are many style options for visualization. Some examples are:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}
\begin{document}
\title{GROUP THEORY}\bfseries
\maketitle
\section{ALGEBRIC SYSTEM :}

\begin{tcolorbox}
NOTE: The algebraic system define over operator $\star$ , which is \emph{closed} and \emph{associative} is called SEMIGROUP.
\end{tcolorbox}

\begin{tcolorbox}[title=NOTE:,colframe=blue,colback=blue!5!white,arc=0pt,fonttitle=\bfseries]
The algebraic system define over operator $\star$ , which is \emph{closed} and \emph{associative} is called SEMIGROUP.
\end{tcolorbox}

\newtcbtheorem[number within=section]{note}{Note}{enhanced,drop fuzzy shadow,
  colframe=red!75!black,colback=red!5!white,
  colbacktitle=red!10!white,coltitle=red!20!black}{note}

\begin{note}{}{somenote}
The algebraic system define over operator $\star$ , which is \emph{closed} and \emph{associative} is called SEMIGROUP.
\end{note}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: i want simple box not colourerd

Comment: Can you specify 'simple'? If you use the options `colframe=black,colback=white,arc=0pt,outer arc=0pt` you will get a rectangular box with white interior.

Answer (score 2):

I'd use `mdframed` as in my [previous post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/117927/9823)

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[framemethod=tikz]{mdframed}

\definecolor{cccolor}{rgb}{.67,.7,.67}
\begin{document}

\begin{mdframed}[outerlinecolor=black,outerlinewidth=2pt,linecolor=cccolor,middlelinewidth=3pt,roundcorner=10pt]
  This work is licensed under a Creative Commons Attribution-ShareAlike 3.0 Unported License.
  \begin{center}
    \includegraphics[scale=2]{by-nc-sa.pdf}
  \end{center}
\end{mdframed}

\end{document}
```

giving...

[image: mdframed box with TikZ]