# package to include the software license

Tags: licensing

I want to include the text of software licenses (MIT, Apache, etc) in my report.

Is there a package to package to do this?

Basically i'm looking for something similar to [lipsum](https://ctan.org/pkg/lipsum), where i can:

```
\usepackage{lipsum}
...
\begin{document}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

*UPDATE*:

If there's no such package, is it a good idea to create a tex package and submit to CTAN?

Comment: Maybe `doclicense` (https://www.ctan.org/pkg/doclicense) does what you want?

Comment: thanks for the pointer. unfortunately, `Cur­rently, only Creative Com­mons is sup­ported, but this pack­age is de­signed to han­dle all kinds of li­censes.`

Comment: the `doclicense` points to this [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/117597/inserting-a-creative-commons-licence-into-a-latex-document/226788#226788)

Comment: If you want to contribute, you could make a feature request in the repository and offer to provide the license text in the required format.

Comment: github repo: https://github.com/ypid/latex-packages/tree/master/doclicense