# Usage of CC License in a thesis

Tags: pdftex, thesis, licensing

I'd like to insert a CC license on my thesis. I've selected the CC-BY-SA, but I couldn't proceed further, as to do I just download the image, concerning text and use it?

Q: Can anyone please provide info as if there's a confirmation mail for using a CC license? That would be really helpful!

Comment: Uhm, I might be wrong but this does not really sound like a TeX question...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I generate Creative Commons license information?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1725/how-do-i-generate-creative-commons-license-information)

Comment: This question is not about TeX/LaTeX.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use `doclicence`.

```
% License:
% This work is licensed under the Creative Commons Attribution 4.0 International License. To view a copy of this license, visit http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/4.0/.
%
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[
    type={CC},
    modifier={by-sa},
    version={4.0},
]{doclicense}
\begin{document}
\doclicenseThis
\end{document}
```

[image: licence]

Comment: Thanks, I was just wondering if there an acknowledgment or something that I need to get from CC License website.